# Run crontab to click a website link every hour

Tags: php, website, cron, curl

I would like to click on a test like [this](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php) (the "start testing" button) every hour so I can get a hourly result (results are saved on the server side). Basically what happens is that I connect with a server to them and they send me a java applet (`GlasnostReplayer.jar`) that runs in my browser. If I do have the jar file and run `java -jar GlasnostReplayer.jar`, I get `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from ... .jar`. (Besides, I think I need the connection to the server before I run the applet, and not just run the applet on my side). How can I achieve such a task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PHP CURL will help you to deal with links.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Hmm, I see now that I need to write something with php/curl then use crontab to run that hourly. That's one big step in the right direction. I'm new to curl and php, I don't know where to start. Can you give me a guide? further details for what I'm trying to accomplish? and curl would let me actually run the test after the click? thanks!

Comment: Would this be right? `curl -d "measure=yes&repeat=3&duration=20&down=yes&up=yes&port=0&port2=0&protocol1=BitTorrent"  http://loki09.mpi-sws.mpg.de/bb//glasnost.php`But, I don't think this works, the test wasn't initiated. 
`